# Need help in extracting data from "cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js"

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$response = Http::get('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js');
    
$res = $response->body();

$enc = json_decode($res,true);
```

giving me null I need the rates object.

Comment: If we look at the content of https://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js we can see that it's not JSON, it's in the form of a JavaScript code snippet. Therefore json_decode() cannot be used with it. It seems to be expecting that you would request it via a JSONP request from the front-end (i.e. an AJAX request using JavaScript).

Comment: @ADyson yes that is the problem how to convert it into php array ?

Comment: You can't, because it's not parseable as JSON.

Comment: what about PHP array then?

Comment: any regular expression that can extract the data?

Comment: Not so easily, I don't think. You'd have to strip all the bits at the beginning and the end which aren't usable, then put all the field names in double-quotes and add a missing bracket to the end, by the looks of it. Might be easier to make a JSONP request to it from your front-end, extract the data you want and then send that to your PHP backend via another AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the suggestion from ADyson in the comment above. However, if you must do it on the PHP backend, you can try the following:

```
    $response = Http::get('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js');

    $res = $response->body();

    $res = trim(str_replace("var Currency=", "", $res));
    $res = str_replace(",convert:function(D,R,S){return D*this.rates[R]/this.rates[S]}};", "", $res);
    $res = str_replace("//# sourceMappingURL=/s/javascripts/currencies.js.map", "", $res);
    $res = str_replace('{', '{"', $res);
    $res = str_replace(':', '":"', $res);
    $res = str_replace(',', '","', $res);
    $res = str_replace('}', '"}', $res);
    $res = str_replace('"rates":"', '"rates":', $res);
    $res = str_replace("\n", "", $res);
    $red = htmlentities($res);
    $res = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $res);
    $res = trim($res);
    $res = str_replace('"{', '{', $res);
    $res = str_replace('}"', '}', $res);
    $res = $res."}";
    $enc = json_decode($res, true);
```

Note you can use floatval() when using each of the currency values to convert to number.

```
    $ved_rate = floatval($enc["rates"]["VED"]);
```

Comment: The only thing I'd warn here is that it converts all the numbers to strings, which might or might not be an issue for some people. Demo: https://3v4l.org/v7pNp . Probably not a big deal in most cases due to PHP's loose typing, but it's worth pointing out the caveat. Otherwise, it works well.

Comment: You're right, you can use floatval() to convert each string to number

Comment: The trouble though is knowing which fields were intended to be numeric to begin with. It so happens in this case they all are, but I don't know if that's guaranteed when the file changes.

Comment: Yes, the big problem is if the file structure changes. It's better to handle in frontend with JS. But if it not possible, then file has to be monitored and the code updated if there are any changes.